# How to give file or folder of file as an output in Java swing?

Tags: java, swing

I know its a very specific question but this is the situation:

I am taking one file as an input using BROWSE dialog box of swing.

Now I am converting that file into other file.

So when conversion is completed.
At best I want that **file to be opened in any editor** 
OR
may be we can just **open a window which shows folder** which contains that file as shown in fig.
Is this possible?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to open windows explorer window:

```
public static void selectObjectInExplorer(final String path) throws Exception {
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    rt.exec("explorer /select," + path);
}
```

if you want to open the file using default application you can use Desktop class

```
  public static void openFile(final String path) throws IOException{
        File file = new File(path);
        if ( file.exists() ) {
            Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
            desktop.open(file);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

In Java 6, you can use the `java.awt.Desktop.open()` method to open the file in the preferred editor for that file type, in a platform-independent way. I think that's your best bet.

Comment: @SRK: you accepted the wrong answer. Don't accept Wajdy just because he spoon-fed you the code after copying Ernest's idea. Accept Ernest's because he gave you the correct answer first.